# Does rsyslog support circular log file?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I want to limit the size of log file, if the size has been exceeded, the old messages will be dropped silently, just like a **ring buffer**.

And I think the [output channel](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/output_channels.html) does not meet my requirment.

So, what can I do?

For more, I find a [clog patch](http://software.wheelhouse.org/syslogd/) for syslogd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer only for rsyslog.

There are many ways to make circular log, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392908/circular-log-in-linux).

For example.

> local7.*    /var/log/messages

Then use **omprog** to merge those ways into rsyslog.

> local7.*    action(type="omprog" binary="/path/ways")

We can use many ways as above to record the logs into a circular buffer.

One more sentence, because the circular format is so customized, which needs an according tool to load the content. I think this is why rsyslog does not support such formal plugin.

Answer (score 1):

use rotate 0 to keep only one file

```
"/var/log/sample.log" {
  minsize 9M
  rotate 0
}
```

> **man rotate**
>
> ```
>    rotate count
>           Log files are rotated count times before being removed or
>           mailed to the address specified in a mail directive.  If count
>           is 0, old versions are removed rather than rotated.  If count
>           is -1, old logs are not removed at all (use with caution, may
>           waste performance and disk space). Default is 0.
> ```

Comment: I think "copytruncate" will truncate all the content of the original file. It is not my want.

Comment: yes... but it doesn't affect here as we are not copying any files... @lxyscls

Comment: hmm. say the limit is 10MB, and there come 1MB new messages, I just want the old 9MB messages and the new 1MB to keep in the log file by order. So I don't know why rsyslog does not support such format, and I think it is common.